# OrientDB teleporter fails to convert GIS data from PostGis

Tags: postgis, orientdb

**I am trying to import a large postgresql database into OrientDB with some spatial data stored using PostGIS.**

While teleporter can deal with most of the standard tables it fails to convert any of the geometry fields. Typical error messages are of the form:

> **ERROR**: Problem encountered during the extraction of the values from
>   the records. Vertex Type: TR_AirNodes;   Property: geom; Record: id:1
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException -
>   Error on unmarshalling JSON content
>   '0101000020346C00000000000028AC174100000000B4C92841': content must be
>   between { }^
>           DB name="nis1e"

The tables appear in the output OrientDB database but lack any geometry fields. This occurs with both the 2.2 version and 3.0.0RC2 version of the community edition of OrientDB.

The PostGIS geometry data includes points, lines and areas which can be viewed OK using e.g. QGIS on the Postgres database.

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Teleporter does not support PostGIS because of licensing issues.

BTW this column apart, does the migration succeed? If you need these specific fields in OrientDB there is not a simple quick solution now, but if you just want to avoid this exception you can exclude the in question columns during the migration.

Comment: Thanks for that. It would be good if the error message could mention the underling problem. The migration mainly works as these errors on extraction of the geometry are not fatal and result in tables that have all the correct columns (or vertices) apart from the geometry.